# I want to send the value in useEffect to the parent component, what should I do?

Tags: reactjs

I made a `useEffect` that receives the API and I want to pass the value in `useEffect` to the parent component. I'm trying to send the value of `userData.data.isSuccess`, but an error occurs because it's not a function. I know I have to make it into a function, but I don't know how to make it. Can you tell me how to make and pass it? I'd appreciate it if you let me know thanks

**SignUpUserInput:**

this is child component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';
import redX from '../../resources/images/img/redX.png'
import axios from 'axios';

const InputWrap = styled.div`
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 219);
  border-radius: 3px;
`

function SignUpUserInput({userName,setUserName,toParentUser}) {


useEffect (()=> {
  async function fetchData () {
    try{
      const userData = await axios({
        method : 'get',
        url : `https://cors-anywher.herokuapp.com/https://clone-instagram.shop:8080/users/checkid?id=${userName}`
      });

      //I want to send this..
      toParentUser(userData.data.isSuccess)
      console.log(userData.data.isSuccess);
    }

    catch(error) {
      alert(error);
    }
  }
  fetchData();
},[userName])
 
 

  return (
    <InputWrap isUserName={isUserName}>
      <label className='inputLabel'>
        <span className='inputHover'>
          사용자 이름
        </span>
        <input className='inputInput' value={userName} onChange={(e)=>{setUserName(e.target.value); onCheckName(e);}}/>
      </label>
    </InputWrap>
  )
}

export default SignUpUserInput;
```

**SignUp:**

and this is parent component. I want deliver `serData.data.isSuccess` to this component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';
import SignUpUserInput from '../components/SingUp/SignUpUserInput';


const SignUpWrap = styled.div`
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  margin-bottom: calc(-100vh + 0px);

`

function SignUp() {


  
  const toParentUser = (x) => {
    console.log('well done', x)
  }


  const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
 

  return (
    <SignUpWrap>
      
      <div className='signUpInputContent4'>
        <SignUpUserInput userName={userName} setUserName={setUserName} />
      </div>
              
    </SignUpWrap>
  )
}

export default SignUp;
```

Comment: You are not passing `toParentUser` to the component...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on the comment mentioned above,

You didn't pass the function as a prop to the child component.
You only passed other props and forgot to pass the `toParentUser` props.

You did:

```
<SignUpUserInput userName={userName} setUserName={setUserName} />
```

Instead of:

```
<SignUpUserInput userName={userName} setUserName={setUserName} toParentUser={toParentUser} />
```